# Grouping Objects from Different classes using java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the classes below

```
class Pojo1 {
    pojo2 item;
}

class pojo2 {
    pojo3 item;
}

class pojo3 {
   pojo4 item;
}
```

I want to accumulate them as below from a stream of pojo1. (Stream multiple)

```
Map<pojo4,Map<pojo3,List<pojo2>>>  k=new HashMap()<>;
```

Can anyone help me do this in streams? And also I want to sort the map on attributes below:

```
   (pojo4 - some property)
   (pojo3 - some property)
   (pojo2- some property)
```

I would like to do this using both java 8 stream and parallel streams.

Answer (score 1):

First, the mentioned POJO classes `Pojo4` and `Pojo3` need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` in order to be used as map keys as well as relevant getters for the properties.

The conversion should use common `Collectors.groupingBy` / `Collectors.mapping` collectors, and initial remapping to a plain container of two objects such as `Pair` is needed.

The example below uses Java 11 `Map.entry` as an intermediate container.

```java
static Map<Pojo4, <Map<Pojo3, List<Pojo2>>>> convert(Stream<Pojo1> ones) {
    return ones              // Stream<Pojo1>
        .map(Pojo1::getItem) // Stream<Pojo2>
        .map(p2 -> Map.entry(p2, p2.getItem())) // Stream<Map.Entry<Pojo2, Pojo3>>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            me -> me.getValue().getItem(), // key: Pojo4
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                me -> me.getValue(), // key: Pojo3
                Collectors.mapping(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList()
                )
            )
        ));
}
```

---

Similarly, sorted version may be implemented using `Collectors.groupingBy` with map supplier; additionally `List<Pojo2>` should be sorted using `collectingAndThen`.

Assuming that `Pojo2`, `Pojo3`, `Pojo4` have getter `getField` for the property to sort, the following update is provided:

```java
static Map<Pojo4, <Map<Pojo3, List<Pojo2>>>> convert(Stream<Pojo1> ones) {
    return ones
        .map(Pojo1::getItem) // Stream<Pojo2>
        .map(p2 -> Map.entry(p2, p2.getItem())) // Stream<Map.Entry<Pojo2, Pojo3>>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            me -> me.getValue().getItem(), // key: Pojo4
            () -> new TreeMap(Comparator.comparing(Pojo4::getField)),
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                me -> me.getValue(), // key: Pojo3
                () -> new TreeMap(Comparator.comparing(Pojo3::getField)),
                Collectors.mapping(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toList(), // List<Pojo2>
                        list -> {
                            list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Pojo2::getField)); 
                            return list;
                        }
                    )
                )
            )
        ));
}
```

---

Disclaimer: the code samples above have not been tested, so additional tweaking may be needed.

Comment: Thanks but its not working can it get any simpler to understand :( Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Map<Object,List<Object>>> to Map<pojo4,Map<pojo3,List<pojo2>>>

Comment: _What_ is not working?  There are plenty things to define in the pojo classes.

Comment: _can it get any simpler_ I'm afraid not.

Comment: new TreeMap(Comparator.comparing(Pojo3::getField)),new TreeMap(Comparator.comparing(Pojo4::getField))          what could be Type arguments for both treemaps?   as in <K,V> info?

Comment: can you please tell what the groupBy and mapping operations result to?

Comment: `groupingBy` creates maps with the mentioned types as keys: outer map using `Pojo4` objects as keys, then nested map using `Pojo3` as keys; to get the values of nested map as `List<Pojo2>` the collector `Collectors.mapping` is used.

Comment: Therefore TreeMap could be created using [constructor accepting comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) -- this implies that `Pojo4::getField`, `Pojo3::getField` should return `Comparable` objects.